# Do tickers in golang overwrite already running processes?

Tags: go

For example, if I have something like:

```
t := time.NewTicker(time.Second*1)
for {
  select {
   case <-t.C:
     runSomeExpensiveFunction() // takes over 1 second
  }
  // ...
}
```

And let's say `runSomeExpensiveFunction` prints numbers from 1 to 1 trillion in a loop.

Is `runSomeExpensiveFunction` guaranteed to finish running or will Golang kill it and run it again everytime a new tick is received?

I've done some manual testing and it seems that golang will **wait** for this function to finish before going onto the next tick, but this feels wrong to me.

Comment: Are you, by chance, expecting something like JavaScript's `setInterval`?

Answer (score 3):

First, Go will never just kill a go routine. `runSomeExpensiveFunction` will run until it finishes.

Secondly, only one `runSomeExpensiveFunction` will ever run at a time given the code we can see here. It's incorrect to think of this as "everytime a new tick is received", because nothing is "receiving" a tick. Your `select` executes *one branch* and then it's done, it's the `for { }` that causes the `select` to be executed many times, and the end of the `for` isn't reached until `runSomeExpensiveFunction` returns.

Your `select` will invoke `runSomeExpensiveFunction`, and the flow of execution will enter that function, and the `select` is done. The timer might emit its next tick over its channel, but nothing is listening for it. It's only when your function returns that the flow of execution hits the end of your `for { }` and returns to the top, where it encounters the `select` again, and the `case` that reads from the timer's channel is tested.

If you want to have multiple invocations of your function running concurrently, that's what the `go` keyword is for:

```
   case <-t.C:
     go runSomeExpensiveFunction()
```

You should note that, if the function takes more than a second, you'll be looking at unbounded parallelism and your program will eventually crash.

Answer (score 2):

[`t.C`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Ticker) isn't magic. `t.C` returns a channel. `<-t.C` tries to read from the channel. The channel blocks for the duration and then returns a Time.

`select` picks the first channel which isn't blocking. In your code it will wait until `t.C` returns a tick and then run `runSomeExpensiveFunction`.

For example, this will print 1, 2, then time out.

```
func handle(a int) {
  time.Sleep(time.Second*2)
  fmt.Println(a)
}

func main() {
  t := time.NewTicker(time.Second*1)

  c := make(chan int, 2)

  c<-1
  c<-2

  for {
    select {
    case m := <-c:
      handle(m)
    case <-t.C:
      fmt.Println("timed out")
    }
  }
}
```

1. `select` tries to read from `c` and `t.C`. `c` returns immediately so `handle` runs.
2. `select` tries to read from `c` and `t.C`. `c` returns immediately so `handle` runs.
3. `select` tries to read from `c` and `t.C`. `c` is empty so `<-c` blocks. `<-t.C` blocks for a second and returns a Time and prints `timed out`.

And it repeats step 3.